# Error converting String to Char array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to convert a String to a char array so that I can search char by char in it:

```
char[] arr = new char[str.length()];
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
}
do {
    //   Something
} while (arr[i] != " ");
```

but last line gives this error in Eclipse:

> Incompatible operand types Char and String

Even when I use method `toCharArray`, the error remains. Can anybody explain to me why?

Comment: I think you should have a look at regular expressions and String.split if you want to analyze a string word by word.

Comment: the  `toCharArray` *will* work, but you're currently looking at comparing a String value (not a char). Just change your last line to `}while(arr[i]!=' ');` and you should be flying!

Comment: I can't see how converting to a `char[]` will help you search word-by-word.  `String` has plenty of methods that make it easy to work with sequences of characters--`indexOf`, `substring`, and already-mentioned `split` and regular expressions, that you can't use on `char[]`.

Comment: you are comparing char arr[i] with string " ", use single quotes

Comment: OK, even with the change to "search char by char", I still think working with a `String` would be easier because of regexes and `indexOf`.

Comment: @ajb I would *tend* to agree, but it all depends on what the OP is doing with it :(

Comment: @MurtazaZaidi Using the "back-tick" (reverse quote mark) character when you post a comment, around things that look like code, will help avoid readability problems with things like quote marks.  The back-tick is usually on the same key as `~`.  Put a back-tick on each side of the text you want to show up as "code".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`" "` is a String, while `charAt` returns primitive type `char`. You can't compare these two types with `==`. Instead use `char` representing space so you will end up with `char == char` which works fine. Use

```
while(arr[i]!=' ');
```

or

```
while(!Character.isSpaceChar(arr[i]));
```

Comment: I edited your answer a little to add some clarifications. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Can you add this as an option. while(!Character.isSpaceChar(arr[i]))

Comment: @ControlAltDel Just looks neater and make OP getting used to making static calls and inbuilt function rather than re inventing the wheel ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
while(arr[i] != ' ') // Single quotation marks.
{
    // Code
}
```

**OR**

```
while(!Character.isSpaceChar(arr[i])) {

    // Code
}
```

`Java` is not `PHP`.
Single quotations in `Java` can strictly contain only one character. While double quotes are strictly used to represent strings.

Comment: You forgot negation in your second example (OP wants to check if character *isn't* space).